# How to to filter out duplicated objects inside a list based on a key?

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of objects:

```
[
 Phone('name': 'iPhone-14', 'updated_date': '2022-11-12', 'status': 'available'),
 Phone('name': 'iPhone-14', 'updated_date': '2023-10-12', 'status': 'sold'),
 Phone('name': 'Samsung-S20', 'updated_date': '2022-10-12', 'status': 'available'),
 Phone('name': 'Samsung-S20', 'updated_date': '2020-10-12', 'status': 'available'),
 Phone('name': 'Samsung-S10', 'updated_date': '2020-10-12', 'status': 'sold'),
 Phone('name': 'iPhone-14', 'updated_date': '2022-04-01', 'status': 'available'),
 Phone('name': 'Samsung-S10', 'updated_date': '2022-12-11', 'status': 'sold'),
]
```

I want to keep the object with the LAST "updated_date" of each "name" IF its status is "available". If no "available" status found for that specific name, I just keep the last updated_date one of it.

For the example above, I would get:

```
[
 Phone('name': 'iPhone-14', 'updated_date': '2022-11-12', 'status': 'available'),
 Phone('name': 'Samsung-S20', 'updated_date': '2022-10-12', 'status': 'available'),
 Phone('name': 'Samsung-S10', 'updated_date': '2022-12-11', 'status': 'sold'),
]
```

What's the most efficient way to do it instead of going into many multiple loops?

Comment: How is the class `Phone` defined?

Comment: What is **Phone** ? It's neither a class nor a function

Answer (score 0):

Basic strategy: sort by by attribute (name, ...), make groups and apply the filter condition.

About efficiency: it is sensible on the implementation of the class (?) `Phone`.

Here an example:

```
# minimal Phone class for a working example
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Phone:
    name:str
    updated_date:str
    status:str


# body of the program
from datetime import date
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter, eq


def p_sort(phones):
    out = []
    p_ordered = sorted(phones, key=lambda p: (
                    p.name, 
                    -date.fromisoformat(p.updated_date).toordinal(), # newest 1st
                    p.status))
    
    # classification
    for _, grp in groupby(p_ordered, key=attrgetter('name')):
        # make newest first
        g = list(grp)
        # check by available
        p = next(filter(lambda p: eq(p.status, "available"), g), None)
        if not p:
            # check by sold
            p = next(filter(lambda p: eq(p.status, "sold"), g))
        
        # update
        out.append(p)
    
    return out[::-1] # reverse the list


# list of Phone classes
phones = [
 Phone(name='iPhone-14', updated_date='2022-11-12', status='available'),
 Phone(name='iPhone-14', updated_date='2023-10-12', status='sold'),
 Phone(name='Samsung-S20', updated_date='2022-10-12', status='available'),
 Phone(name='Samsung-S20', updated_date='2020-10-12', status='available'),
 Phone(name='Samsung-S10', updated_date='2020-10-12', status='sold'),
 Phone(name='iPhone-14', updated_date='2022-04-01', status='available'),
 Phone(name='Samsung-S10', updated_date='2022-12-11', status='sold'),
]  

p_sort(phones)
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) but wondering what's the purpose of using the underscore (_) here? in the for loop I mean

Comment: it is used to denote smt that you are not going to use, to add readability. In this specific case it will be the phone's name